# How do I find what commit version I have?

Tags: python, git, pip, commit

I know [how to install a specific commit from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685920/install-specific-git-commit-with-pip) but how do I find what commit version I have? 
`pip freeze | grep package` doesn't list the commit version and I didn't see anything in the docs for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might not be possible: "pip's ability to discern where the install came from is limited after the fact using pip freeze."  See this link: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/609

Discussion on SO: [Pip freeze does not show repository paths for requirements file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560056/pip-freeze-does-not-show-repository-paths-for-requirements-file)