# python pip freeze with a custom link that was used to install a package

Tags: python, pip

I have a .whl package which is hosted in the cloud. I'm able to do

```
pip install https://somelink.com/package.whl
```

Which works fine. But when I do

```
pip freeze > file
```

I get the package

```
package==some_version
```

I would like to get

```
https://somelink.com/package.whl
```

How can I get the link to the package instead of the package name?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip freeze does not show repository paths for requirements file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560056/pip-freeze-does-not-show-repository-paths-for-requirements-file)

Comment: not a duplicate, as I'm using .whl and -e does not work in this instance